# Titanium Appcelerator parent window close the new window as well

Tags: window, titanium, parent

I am trying to open a new window and close its parent window, so that I can't return to previous window and keep the application more efficient.

However calling close on parent window causes the new window to be closed as well, regardless if I call it before opening the new window or after.
What happens is new window is being opened and then closed right away.
I tried to open a new window on the event listener close for parent window... but that doesn't help.

Code example:

```
`app.js:`
var loginWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url:login.js
});
loginWin.open();


`login.js:`

var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({.....});
btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){

    //putting win.close() also causes the problem
    var appCoreWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
      url:"core.js"
    });
    win.close();
    appCoreWidnow.open();
});
win.add(btn);
```

Comment: Can you post example code to see how you are trying to achieve this effect and then someone can make adjustments to it?

Comment: Sorry, first time posting a question))  Please check the code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating Window object inside eventhandler and when function finishes garbage collector removes all local variables from it, including appCoreWindow.

Try this instead:

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var appCoreWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({ url:"core.js" });

var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({.....});
btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    appCoreWidnow.open();
    win.close();
});
win.add(btn);
```

Comment: Didn't exactly helped, but now I know where to look for an error. Thank you very much)

Comment: If you found different solution to your problem, could you post it as an answer here, so other users of StackOverflow could see it?

Comment: What I did is defined the login window in app.js rather than in login.js and made transition to the core.js from there.  Not exactly the intended way, but does the trick.  And of course created the new window outside of eventListener, which seems to be was the problem.